# How to apply assertion in REST API testing through soap UI

Tags: api, rest, functional-testing, assertions

I am namrata ...

I have been doing REST API testing in my company. I a new for API testing.

I have done simple REST API testing using SoupUI.

*My Question:* I would like to know, how can I go for assertions in REST API using SoupUI testing tool.

Please let me know the steps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Which assertion? And what is "the soap UI"? Which API?
Please define your question better.

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of ways you can add assertions.

1. XPath
2. Xquery
3. Script Assertion etc...

The given screenshot is the way to add the XPath assertion..

[image]